# Python list of string harmonization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list unique string as below:

```
unique_region=['REGION-A', 'REGION-B','REGION-C','REGION-AB', 'REG-A','REG-B','REG-C', 'REG-AB','R-A','AB']
```

I would like to process the list and return a harmonized list with python as below:

```
harmonized_region=['REG-A', 'REG-B', 'REG-C', 'REG-AB', 'REG-A', 'REG-B','REG-C','REG-AB','REG-A','REG-AB']
```

I tried creating dictionary manually to match the unique data to the harmonized data, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
unique_region=['REGION-A', 'REGION-B','REGION-C','REGION-AB', 'REG-A','REG-B','REG-C', 'REG-AB','R-A','AB']
harmonized_region=['REG-'+i.split('-')[-1] for i in unique_region]
print(harmonized_region)
```

gives output

```
['REG-A', 'REG-B', 'REG-C', 'REG-AB', 'REG-A', 'REG-B', 'REG-C', 'REG-AB', 'REG-A', 'REG-AB']
```

Explanation: I split at `-`, get last element `[-1]` and prefix it with `REG-`. Observe that if `-` is not present whole string become last element.

Comment: is there any alternatives in any case the data does not come with hyphen '-' ? As example the data only comes as 'REGION A' or 'REGION AMSTERDAM' (REGION AMSTERDAM is REG-A)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this conclusion:

```
unique_region=['REGION-A', 'REGION-B','REGION-C','REGION-AB', 'REG-A','REG-B','REG-C', 'REG-AB','R-A','AB']
harmonized_region=[]
for i in range(len(unique_region)):
    harmonized_region.append('REG-'+unique_region[i].split('-')[-1])
print(harmonized_region)
```

Result :

```
['REG-A', 'REG-B', 'REG-C', 'REG-AB', 'REG-A', 'REG-B', 'REG-C', 'REG-AB', 'REG-A', 'REG-AB']
```

In the comment above, you said that if there is no "-", you should leave it empty in the split() method because it separates based on space and puts it in the list.

I hope it is useful